# Sending resumes in Sweden while being a visitor there

Tags: work, sweden, tourism

I have been sending resumes to various companies, including to those located in Sweden, while living outside of Sweden. Now I'm planning to take a trip to Sweden for a short while, not to work, but for the sake of exploring the country. There is no need for me to look for a job in Sweden in-person, all can be done remotely these days, including job interviews. I would like to continue applying for jobs, including for jobs in Sweden, while being present in Sweden as a tourist.

Is this allowed or not? I don't have EU citizenship, but I'm allowed to stay for 90 days out of every 180 days visa-free, if this is at all relevant.

Comment: The main question is: how will the authorities get to know what you do once entered? Sometimes it's just a matter of being smart and practical.

Comment: I'm not sure about Sweden, but in general it is not illegal to look for work while visiting a country on a non-work visa.

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ I agree, but I'm just a little concerned if I can specify in my resumes my current Swedish address, just in case they want to have an in-person interview (some still prefer that). Or if, when I apply for a work visa, an immigration official will have to know when I applied for the job, etc.

Comment: Giving a Swedish address might give the employer the impression that you already have a residency/work permit. The process for the employer is much more complicated when you don't. Give them your current home address and write a line about being available for an interview during your trip. You must go back home and apply for a work permit anyway.

Comment: The other issue about giving a Swedish address is that (depending on the type of job you are looking for) it can take weeks or even months between sending your CV and getting an interview or job offer: how long are you planning to stay at that address?

Comment: @StuartF Yes, but there's been a company which contacted me just about 2-3 days after I sent a resume.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed. I base this on the lack of a law forbidding it. The chapter in the law about specific requirements on foreigners is rather short (chapter 2 in [utlänningslag](https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/dokument-lagar/dokument/svensk-forfattningssamling/utlanningslag-2005716_sfs-2005-716)). Regarding work I only find:

> Arbetstillstånd är ett tillstånd att arbeta i Sverige. En utlänning som skall arbeta i Sverige på grund av anställning här eller utomlands skall ha arbetstillstånd.

> *A work permit is a permit to work in Sweden. An alien who is to work in Sweden due to employment here or abroad must have a work permit.*

Looking for employment is obviously not employment.

Comment: While your last sentence is technically true, looking for employment while in a country for which you don't have a work permit could give authorities pause to consider that you are looking to work illegally in that country.

Comment: @Peter The question was "Is this allowed or not?" Not whether it is a good idea :-) But, of course, OP should consider you comment. You can't get a work permit without having a job offering so sending resumes from abroad and then travel to Sweden for an interview isn't that much of a difference.

Comment: I don't know how applicable this is to Sweden, but back in the day I heard numerous stories about people being refused entry into the UK because they were found to be carrying a copy of their resume.

Comment: To visit UK I think you must have a reason. So if you claim tourism as reason with a resume in your luggage I guess you could be refused. Sweden don't have any "reason" requirement https://www.migrationsverket.se/English/Private-individuals/Visiting-Sweden/If-you-do-not-need-a-visa-to-travel-to-Sweden.html My **guess** is that if you fulfill all requirements and seem knowledgeable about the work permit process you will be let through even if you tell the border police that you will be sending resumes.